# Making a row (in a pickerview) not selectable after selected in a UItextField with same pickerview

Tags: swift, uipickerview

I have been looking for answers but I couldn't find any clear solution. I am making a view controller with three UItextFields with same UIpickerViews. How can I make a specific row not selectable change color or disappear) if it is already selected in another UItextField?

Here's my code:

```
 }
func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, numberOfRowsInComponent component: Int) -> Int {
    return Array.count

}
func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, attributedTitleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> NSAttributedString? {
    if "Shake" {
    let attributesUnavailable = [NSForegroundColorAttributeName: UIColor.gray]
    let attributedTitle = NSAttributedString(string: "Shake", attributes: attributesUnavailable)
        return attributedTitle
    }

    let attributesAvailable = [NSForegroundColorAttributeName: UIColor.black]
    let attributedTitle = NSAttributedString(string: Array[row], attributes: attributesAvailable)
    return attributedTitle
}

public func numberOfComponents(in pickerView: UIPickerView) -> Int {
    return 1
}

func donePicker() {
    actionTextField1.resignFirstResponder()
    actionTextField2.resignFirstResponder()
    actionTextField3.resignFirstResponder()

}

@IBAction func save3(_ sender: AnyObject) {
    if (behaviorTextField1.text?.isEmpty)! {
        let behavior1Empty = UIAlertController (title: "Error", message: "Please fill-In Behavior Names and set corresponding Actions", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.alert)

        self.present(behavior1Empty, animated:true, completion:nil)

         behavior1Empty.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Okay", style: UIAlertActionStyle.default, handler: { (action: UIAlertAction!) in


    }))

}
}
    func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView, didSelectRow row: Int, inComponent component: Int) {

        if Array[row] {
            pickerView.selectRow(row + 1, inComponent: 0, animated: true)
        }
    }
    if pickerView.tag == 1 {
        actionTextField1.text = Array[row]

    }
    else if pickerView.tag == 2 {
        actionTextField2.text = Array[row]
    }
    else {
        actionTextField3.text = Array[row]
```

}
Help will be highly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

It not so simple like `UITableView`, but there is a nice approach which seems to be the same used when setting IOS Date at Settings.app.

- First set the invalid row title attribute color to be gray, so the user will know this row is unavailable:
  [pickerView(_:attributedTitleForRow:forComponent:)](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uipickerviewdelegate/1614375-pickerview)

Example:

```
func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView, attributedTitleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> NSAttributedString? {

if row_cant_be_selected {
    let attributesUnavailable = [NSForegroundColorAttributeName: UIColor.grayColor()]
    let attributedTitle = NSAttributedString(string: YOUR_TITLE_FOR_ROW, attributes: attributesUnavailable)
    return attributedTitle
}

let attributesAvailable = [NSForegroundColorAttributeName: UIColor.blackColor()]
let attributedTitle = NSAttributedString(string: YOUR_TITLE_FOR_ROW, attributes: attributesUnavailable)
return attributedTitle
}
```

- Then use delegate's method [pickerView(_:didSelectRow:inComponent:)](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uipickerviewdelegate/1614371-pickerview) to know when users selected an unavailable row. In this method just call `selectRow(_:inComponent:animated:)` to "force" another row selection.

Example:

```
func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView, didSelectRow row: Int, inComponent component: Int) {

        if ROW_CANT_BE_SELECTED {
            pickerView.selectRow(row + 1, inComponent: 0, animated: true)
        }
}
```

IE: If row 1 is unavailable, on `pickerView(_:didSelectRow:inComponent:` just call `pickerView.selectRow(row + 1, inComponent: 0, animated: true)`. This will make `UIPickerView` to skip to next element. Just watch out for last element.

Please pay attention to `row + 1`, if the current `row` its the last one, you should do `row - 1` instead.

Other approach is to remove those unavailable elements on your data source. Just reload the other picker views data.

Comment: Thanks for your reply @Caio!!! I am really new in programming. Where should I write the pickerView(_:attributedTitleForRow:forComponent:) and set to gray color? and pickerView(_:didSelectRow:inComponent:) ? Thank you!!!

Comment: `pickerView(:attributedTitleForRow:forComponent:)` is part of `UIPickerViewDelegate` which you are already using (`titleForRow`, `didSelectRow` is already functions from delegate). `pickerView(:didSelectRow:inComponent:)` its already on your code you showed. Give a try, if not, I can write some examples for you.

Comment: yeah. this one: 

    }
    func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, attributedTitleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> NSAttributedString? {
       
  
    
How can i set it to gray color?

Comment: Okay, I added some examples. Hope it helps. But its in swift 2.2. Its not so different than Swift 3 (I dont have XCode 8 available right now).

Comment: Thanks Caio! What should I write for "row_cant_be_selected" and String: "Your Title for row"?

Comment: Write your logic. How do you know this row can't be selected? Just wirte on `row_cant_be_selected`. `Your Title for row` its just your string value for your row, the same you are already using on `titleForRow:`. For now on, you will be using *ONLY* `pickerView(:attributedTitleForRow:forComponent:)` instead of  `titleForRow:`. They are just placeholders.

Comment: I am sorry for my limited understanding of swift coding. I am really new in this project. Should I write in row_cant_be_selected : if Shake can't be selected?

Comment: The titleForRow only has return Array [row].

Comment: Yes, write there your logic if this row shouldn't be selected. `Array[row]` return an String. Put this on `YOUR_TITLE_FOR_ROW`

Comment: Can you check the code above? I really don't know what to write. So please help me.